# Get a single value from an ArrayList from a textbox in a messagebox

Tags: c#, arraylist, struct

I am learning Struct and Arraylist for a school exercise, not an assignment. I am wondering what would be the best way to get the grade in a messagebox in my button click event. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be very appreciated, thanks!

```
private ArrayList allGrades = new ArrayList();

public struct Test
{
    public int score;
    public string grade;
}

private void btnFindGrade_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int myGrade = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);

    foreach (Test x in allGrades)
    {

    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Test t;
    t.score = 299;
    t.grade = "F";

    allGrades.Add(t);

    t.score = 349;
    t.grade = "D";

    allGrades.Add(t);

    t.score = 399;
    t.grade = "C";

    allGrades.Add(t);

    t.score = 449;
    t.grade = "B";

    allGrades.Add(t);

    t.score = 500;
    t.grade = "A";

    allGrades.Add(t);
}
```

I forgot to mention, for my application it's just a textbox with a button, I enter a score as you see in my code, and then I want to get the users grade in a messgebox.

Comment: Show us what you tried. I see no reference to a message box in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few answers here and on the web to help achieve your task. First of all, drop the ArrayList since it boxes everything into object and then you need to worry about unboxing.

Use List which will pretty much look like:

```
var allGrades = new List<Test>()
```

Then simply use linq to query:

```
allGrades.FirstOrDefault(x => x.grade == myGrade)
```

Ta-da...job done

Answer (score 0):

First, you, probably want to create several instances of `Test` class:

```
                Test t = new Test();
                t.score = 299;
                t.grade = "F";

                allGrades.Add(t);

                t = new Test(); 
                t.score = 349;
                t.grade = "D";

                allGrades.Add(t);

                t = new Test(); 
                t.score = 399;
                t.grade = "C";

                allGrades.Add(t);

                t = new Test(); 
                t.score = 449;
                t.grade = "B";

                allGrades.Add(t);

                t = new Test(); 
                t.score = 500;
                t.grade = "A";

                allGrades.Add(t);
```

Or shorter version:

```
      allGrades.Add(new Test() {score = 299, grade = "F"});
      allGrades.Add(new Test() {score = 349, grade = "D"});
      allGrades.Add(new Test() {score = 399, grade = "C"});
      allGrades.Add(new Test() {score = 449, grade = "B"});
      allGrades.Add(new Test() {score = 500, grade = "A"});
```

Having collection filled, you can find out the first `Test` item with given grade:

```
      private void btnFindGrade_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        int myGrade = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);

        Test found = allGrades
          .OfType<Test>()
          .FirstOrDefault(item => item.grade == myGrade);

        if (found != null) {
          MessageBox.Show($"score: {found.score} grade: {found.Grade}");
        }
        else 
          MessageBox.Show($"Not found");
      }
```